# I need to count averege but the answer is 1735473548 or something like that

Tags: c, average

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    total = 0;
    counter = 1;

    while(counter <= 10)
    {
        printf("%s", "Enter grade: ");
        scanf("%d", &grade);
        total = total + grade;
        counter = counter + 1;
    }

    average = total / 10;

    printf("%d", "average is:", average);
}
```

I tried to calculate the average of 10 numbers.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Consider using a more idiomatic `for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)` loop.  Don't declare the variable in the loop control; you should divide by `counter` rather than by `10` after the loop ends, so you need `counter` available after the loop ends.  You should check that `scanf()` succeeds, breaking the loop if it fails.  Remember to avoid dividing by zero.  Reread the course notes and manual on [`printf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html).

Answer (score 5):

`printf("%d", "average is:", average);` tells `printf` to take an `int` and print it as a decimal numeral, but `"average is:"` passes it the address of the string instead of an `int`. You should use `printf("The average is %d.\n", average);`.

Compile with warnings enabled and elevated to errors. With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.

Once you get that working, consider making `average` and `total` `double` instead of `int`. Then you will need to change `%d` to another format.

Answer (score 0):

Required when doing math, you must declare double, or float with division. For the most accurate results. If you don't need to get the float point of the result, you don't need to.

In this case, the division operation, you must convert the int type to float type first.
or cast to a float number, the result will be correct.
It's not always the average of a single digit result.

It's a must-know rule.

```
a = b / (c * 1.0)
```

or:

```
a = (float)b / c or a = (b * 1.0)/c
```

or do nothing, if all variables are declared as float, or double.

```
double total = 0.0;
int counter = 1;

while(counter <= 10)
{
    printf("Enter grade: ");
    scanf("%lf", &grade);
    total = total + grade;
    counter = counter + 1;
}

  double average = total / 10;
  printf("average is: %lf", average);
```

Comment: Without knowing the definitions from the OP's code you cannot tell that this might be wrong. Besides that you completely removed the `printf` command in question.

Comment: This isn't an `int` vs. `float` type problem per-se. You also failed to fix the problematic `printf` call.

Comment: You repeated the error of passing wrong parameters to `printf`. The compiler should complain about that call.

Comment: I have edited the code for him lol

Comment: That line is the actual answer. Everything else is based on some assumption not backed by information from the question

Comment: ok sir, it's been a while since i reviewed the C language, and replied on stackoverflow. This guy confused me with this question too haha